# Почему обычная функция внутри обработчика событий не теряет контекст?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Почему обычная функция внутри обработчика событий не теряет контекст, ведь функция внтури функции ссылается на объект window. Например:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.test')

div.addEventListener('click', function() {
console.log(this)
} )
```

```html
<div class="test">Some Text<div>
```

Comment: Почему ты решаил что он ссылается на window? и где тут функция в функции?

Comment: Я имею ввиду как функция переданная в качестве аргумета ссылается на объект div как он с ним связан

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_value_of_this_within_the_handler